# Player Instantiate camera Put it in

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, photon

I instantiate the player in PUN2 and then find the player in the camera update, and when I find the player with FindObject, I find the first thing I meet and other player objects are included, so how can I solve it

```
 public class CameraControl : MonoBehaviourPunCallbacks
    {
        
        [SerializeField]
        Vector3 _delta;
    
        Vector3 offset;
    
        [SerializeField]
        Transform _player;
    
       
        void Update()
        {
            _player = FindObjectOfType<PlayerControl>().transform;
            transform.position = _player.position + _delta;
        }
    }
```

---

```
    void CreateController()
        {
            Transform spawnPoint = SpawnManager.Instance.GetSpawnPoint();
    
            GameObject playerToSpawn = playerPrefabs[0];
            var controller = PhotonNetwork.Instantiate(Path.Combine("PhotonPrefabs", playerToSpawn.name), spawnPoint.position, Quaternion.identity, 0, new object[] { PV.ViewID });
            controller.name = playerToSpawn.name;
        }
```

I made it into a dictionary, put the player and the value of the balloon, and when the value of the balloon is false, the camera passes it, but there is an error. I would appreciate it if you could let me know if there is any other way

Comment: Please don't post code as an image.  Post it as a properly formatted text code block

Comment: I'm sorry. I made a mistake because it was my first time

Comment: is the camera part of the player prefab? if not -> make it ^^ It makes more sense to spawn the camera along with the player and just deactivate/destroy it if it isn't the local player instance  => you can link up the reference within the prefab and don't need any external reference

Comment: A function that finds and receives players externally from the camera. Do you want me to subordinate the camera to the player prefab? I've tried but in that case the camera is spinning with the player so how do I fix it?

Comment: Unparent the camera from the player at runtime.  Something like: `if (photonView.IsMine)  camera.transform.SetParent(null); else Destroy(camera.gameObject);`